# Why we use const and & in this function declaration?

Tags: c++, function, constants

I am new to C++. Wondering what is const and & in the function doing and its meaning.

```
MatrixXd CalculateJacobian(const VectorXd& x_state) {
//blah blah
}
```

Comment: You can get an answer to that in any good, heck even a not so good, textbook.

Comment: I trust even a terrible textbook would bother covering that :)

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, and any post containing `blah blah` should be immediately downvoted into oblivion as a total display of disrespect to the users here.

Comment: The horrible text books tend towards teaching C or Java assuming it's the same as C++, and neither use `&` in quite that fashion.

Comment: Stack overflow should be trying to be the go-to place to answer a question in a good book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a reference (`&`) allows the value to be modified (bad), but saves the compiler making a copy of the object (good).

Making a reference constant,  stops the value from being modified.

So `const someType & value` as a parameter saves a copy and tries to give non-modification promises to the caller.